# SQL in Matlab: Create a date with query

Tags: sql, matlab, date, ms-access

i have daily data:

```
     Isin             Date          Price   
 ______________    ____________    __________ 
'GB00B1YW4409'    '31.12.1999'    [688.1300]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '03.01.2000'    [688.1300]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '04.01.2000'    [690.6200]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '05.01.2000'    [666.9500]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '06.01.2000'    [650.7600]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '07.01.2000'    [663.2200]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '10.01.2000'    [694.3500]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '11.01.2000'    [683.7700]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '12.01.2000'    [675.0500]
'GB00B1YW4409'    '13.01.2000'    [664.4600]
```

I want to have a list of the first of every month. Something like:

```
'01.01.2000'
'01.02.2000'
'01.03.2000'
```

I thought of something like

```
select distinct date(year(List.Date),month(List.Date),01) as Data from List
```

But i get an error message:

```
Error using COM.ADODB_Connection/Execute
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:

Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine

Description: Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression

'date(year(List.Date),month(List.Date),01).
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [`date()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Date-Function-dd7a1f27-d957-4969-ab35-01e0bfbfed76) function in MS Access returns the current date.

You are looking for [`dateserial()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateSerial-Function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503):

```
select distinct dateserial(year(List.Date), month(List.Date), 01) as Data
from List;
```